# LINQ filter specific or all

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I'm passing a filter model to my service. The user can select `any` which is `null` or an empty string. How do i set up a one time `.Where` query that will know to ignore that filter?

An example:

```
public class UserFilterModel
{
    public string State {get; set;};
    public string Age {get; set;};
}
```

The filter: (How do I make it better fit my needs?)

```
var result = context.Users.Where(u => u.State == filter.State && u.Age == filter.Age);
```

So if the user selects null or empty for `State`, this will currently return records with null or empty states when I actually want to ignore that filter.

Also, I'm using asp.net mvc 2, incase I'm doing something completely wrong, please tell me. Using repository pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
var result = context.Users.Where(
    u => (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.State) || u.State == filter.State) &&
         (String.IsNullOrEmpty(filter.Age) || u.Age == filter.Age)
);
```

Comment: what about integers, if it is 0, how do I handle that?

Comment: @Shawn McLean: You mean if you have some property (say `DriverLicenseNumber`) and you want to ignore `DriverLicenseNumber` if `filter.DriverLicenseNumber == 0` is `true`? Simply `(filter.DriverLicenseNumber == 0 || u.DriverLicenseNumber == filter.DriverLicenseNumber)`. The whole point is to utilize short-circuiting to your advantage.